# SQL Server: Counting number of times text occurring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to simply count the number of times "Growth", "Risk", and "Efficiency" occur in the column `oppcat`. Here is the current output which doesn't seem to be adding them as I thought it would: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olVN4.jpg

```
 declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='hospital 1';
SELECT mainhospital,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [oppcat] = 'Growth' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Growth",
       SUM(CASE WHEN [oppcat] = 'Risk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Risk",
       SUM(CASE WHEN [oppcat] = 'Efficiency' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Efficiency"
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
GROUP BY MainHospital;
```

The strange thing is that this query returns `3` for Risk so not sure why the above isn't

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Survey 
WHERE oppcat = 'Risk';
```

Comment: Please show sample data and the results you are getting.  The code looks quite reasonable.

Comment: are the strings only Growth, Risk and efficiency otherwise you will need to do like '%growth%'

Comment: the sample data in the column oppcat are only and exactly "Growth" "Risk" and "Efficiency"

Comment: Your count is counting all hospitals.  Your query has a `where` clause restricting it to one hospital.

Comment: @Gordon, Correct. However this hospital has 3 Risk, 1 Growth, 2 Efficiency

Comment: @user3191137 . . . Please place the data on SQL Fiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com).  To be honest, I trust the query more than your interpretation.  The query says there is one value for each; it is hard to see how this would be calculated incorrectly.

Comment: I tend to agree.  You should just post the result of SELECT *
FROM Survey WHERE oppcat = 'Risk';

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
DECLARE @MainHospital varchar(50)='hospital 1';
SELECT mainhospital, oppcat, COUNT(oppcat)
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
AND oppcat IN ('Growth','Risk','Efficiency')
GROUP BY MainHospital, oppcat;
```

Comment: This is still returning 1's? I'm not sure why, I'll edit my question with something strange

Answer (score 0):

One reason this wouldn't work is if you had a case sensitive collation in operation.  See if this works:

```
SELECT mainhospital,
       SUM(CASE WHEN lower(oppcat) = 'growth' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Growth",
       SUM(CASE WHEN lower(oppcat) = 'risk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Risk",
       SUM(CASE WHEN lower(oppcat) = 'efficiency' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Efficiency"
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
GROUP BY MainHospital;
```

Comment: @user3191137 . . . I would then assume that each of these values occurs in exactly one row for this hospital.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Survey WHERE oppcat = 'Risk';
```

is returning 3 because you're not filtering and grouping by MainHospital.

Please, try this and see what returns:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN [oppcat] = 'Growth' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Growth",
SUM(CASE WHEN [oppcat] = 'Risk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Risk",
SUM(CASE WHEN [oppcat] = 'Efficiency' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Efficiency"
FROM Survey
```

Answer (score -3):

I think Instead of `SUM` You have to Use `COUNT`

```
declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='hospital 1';
SELECT mainhospital,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [oppcat] = 'Growth' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Growth",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [oppcat] = 'Risk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Risk",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [oppcat] = 'Efficiency' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Efficiency"
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
GROUP BY MainHospital;
```

Comment: Absolutely not correct.  `sum()` is the right function to use.

Comment: This will count always regardless its 1 or 0 !!